# Changing TextView LayoutParameters on Button Click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am willing to create a Button named **READ MORE** on click the Layout of `TextView` should turn to `WRAP CONTENT` and **READ MORE** button text should be changed to **SHOW LESS** (this is new button which I created but set visibility `GONE` in xml while **READ MORE** has visibility `VISIBLE`)

So here is the code of mine which work awesome.. on very first click of **READ MORE** and also very first click of **SHOW LESS** but after then if again I click **READ MORE** just only the button gets replaced with **SHOW LESS** and the layout remains same.

- *NOTE: I am placing `TextView` which is inside `LinearLayout` which is inside `CardView`* and its a fragment

XML CODE

```
<LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">


                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/view_project_description"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                                    android:padding="15dp"
                                    android:text="No Description"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black_overlay"
                                    android:textSize="18dp" />


                                <View
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                                    android:background="#44eaeaea" />

                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/view_project_readmore_button"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                                    android:background="#55f4f4f4"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
                                    android:text="Read More >>>"
                                    android:textColor="#3143b3"
                                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/view_project_showless_button"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                                    android:background="#55f4f4f4"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
                                    android:text="Show Less >>>"
                                    android:textColor="#3143b3"
                                    android:textSize="13sp"
                                    android:visibility="gone"/>




                            </LinearLayout>
```

JAVA BUTTON CODE

```
final Button view_project_readmore =(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.view_project_readmore_button);
    final Button view_project_showless = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.view_project_showless_button);
    view_project_showless.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            project_desc.setEnabled(false);
            project_desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int pixels = (int) (80 * scale + 0.5f);
            project_desc.setHeight(500);
            project_desc.setText("This is less Description Now");
            project_desc.setEnabled(true);
            project_desc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view_project_readmore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view_project_showless.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
    });

    view_project_readmore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            project_desc.setEnabled(false);
            //project_desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf");
            project_desc.setTypeface(typeface);
            project_desc.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec non sapien tellus. Suspendisse non sapien nulla. Maecenas ornare velit sit amet consequat hendrerit. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec egestas dignissim enim. Nunc non egestas lacus. Aliquam rhoncus nec urna eu semper. In varius justo augue, eu tincidunt tellus ultricies nec. Pellentesque vel metus sapien.\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "Morbi venenatis ultrices felis et sodales. Suspendisse aliquet justo nec gravida viverra. Nulla condimentum mi ac purus feugiat semper. Ut libero nunc, molestie ac dignissim quis, laoreet vel sapien. Morbi porttitor pulvinar mi, non consectetur lectus posuere ac. Morbi blandit nisl eu diam pretium, maximus mattis orci lobortis. Donec ut tincidunt erat. Donec pharetra, sapien eget mollis vestibulum, felis nisl finibus sapien, tempus laoreet turpis ipsum fermentum eros. Praesent eu nulla facilisis, aliquam massa a, hendrerit risus. Proin at mi odio. Quisque semper, nunc sit amet molestie mattis, quam orci commodo ipsum, ut congue risus dolor eget tellus. Nullam ac mauris in eros condimentum lobortis eget eget ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.");

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = project_desc.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            project_desc.setLayoutParams(params);
            project_desc.setEnabled(true);
            //project_desc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view_project_readmore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view_project_showless.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the height through the layout params in the click listener of the show less button does the trick.

So replace this:

```
project_desc.setHeight(500);
```

With this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = project_desc.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 500;                
project_desc.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Or if you want it to be shorter, this works as well:

```
project_desc.getLayoutParams().height = 500;
```

Comment: I just want to add, please convert that 500 to dp first, because it is in pixel, and pixel is not good for android multi screens

Comment: Tried this but didn't worked,
with the same output, _first time it works while in second click it doesn't work_